# How to find neighboring zipcodes with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, gis

I have a zipcode - let's say "94304". How can I find zip codes that are close to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Now with official public datasets:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT b.zip_code neighbor, b.city, b.county, ST_DISTANCE(a.zcta_geom, b.zcta_geom) distance
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.us_zip_codes` a,
       `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.us_zip_codes` b
  WHERE a.zip_code != b.zip_code
  AND a.zip_code = '94304'
)
WHERE distance < 2000 # 2 KM
ORDER BY distance

-- 5.4s elapsed, 130 MB processed
```

### [image]

With BigQuery GIS and available public data, this is pretty easy and quick:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT b.zipcode neighbor, b.city, b.county, ST_DISTANCE(a.geog, b.geog) distance
  FROM `fh-bigquery.gis.zipcodes` a,
       `fh-bigquery.gis.zipcodes` b
  WHERE a.zipcode != b.zipcode
  AND a.zipcode = '94304'
)
WHERE distance < 2000 # 2 KM
ORDER BY distance

--  Query complete (4.2s elapsed, 130 MB processed)
```

[image]

To get this quick performance, first I transformed the available public data so the geometries in text were already parsed into GIS geometries:

```
CREATE TABLE `gis.zipcodes`
AS
SELECT *, ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(zipcode_geom) AS geog
FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.zipcode_area`
```

Based on:

- https://medium.com/@mentin/given-a-zip-code-find-zip-codes-immediately-bordering-it-ecb7c207ad5f

Comment: This is fantastic. Any idea how I would run this if I wanted to get the results for a large number of zip codes, instead of one? If I remove the AND limiter I start to get CPU limit errors. Thanks!

Comment: Post a new question please

Comment: @FelipeHoffa, what is the difference between geo_us_boundaries and utility_us? Which one has more precise state and county boundaries?

Comment: probably makes more sense to ask as a new question :)